# Defining the constructible universe without model theory

Tags: logic, set-theory, axioms

The constructible powerset is defined in Wikipedia as:

$$\operatorname{Def}(X) := \Bigl\{ \{ y \in X \mid (X,\in) \models \Phi(y,z_1,\ldots,z_n) \}  \Big| \Phi \text{ is a wff and } z_{1},\ldots,z_{n} \in X \Bigr\}.$$

My question is whether this operator can be defined without the "models" notion being used here, only basic set operations. For comparison, consider the finite axiomatization of NBG. In the usual axiomatization we have the "single" axioms: extensionality, pairing, union, powerset, infinity, and limitation of size; plus one axiom schema for comprehension. It was later shown that this axiom schema can be replaced by some eight or so "Godel operators", each of which performs some simple set theoretic operation like $\{(b,(a,c))\mid(a,(b,c))\in R\}$, and together these operations can build anything that the original comprehension schema could produce.

Comment: Will it satisfy you if we just defined the notion of $(X,\in)\models\ldots$ using "basic set operations"?

Comment: @AsafKaragila The problem is basically exactly that, I think - just translate the wff construction rules into operations on classes. Not sure what quantification will look like, though.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're saying. The statement $(X,\in)\models\varphi(y,\vec z)$ is entirely written in the language of set theory. Including $\varphi$ being an object in the universe, rather in the meta-theory.

Comment: @AsafKaragila True, but directly formalizing that statement is somewhat tedious because it involves defining $\varphi$ as a set using Godel numbers or something, and then defining the satisfaction predicate on such objects. It strikes me that this can all be done much simpler by just defining the class operations directly - if my understanding is correct you won't even need finite or countable sequences. I'll post an answer shortly to explain this further.

Comment: Mario, that is not true at all. You're working in the universe of set theory. Formulas are internal strings of characters.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm not sure what you mean. There are formulas in the set theory, and also formulas can be defined as numbers or sets a la Godel. In order to write $(X,\in)\models\phi$ directly you have to use the second of these, which involves many added complications.

Comment: No. You don't need to use any numbering schemes.

Comment: Kunen's book describes this in detail.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Could you be more specific? If you are referring to Kunen "Set Theory", I have the book, and there is a section on the constructible universe, but from what I can tell he does it entirely via model theory (formalizing wffs and the satisfaction predicate), so it doesn't directly apply to the question.

Comment: **Set theory. An introduction to independence proofs**, from 1983.

Comment: I don't want to be excessive, but insisting that $\models$ must be defined via Godel numbering means that you cannot develop any model theory for uncountable languages. You are working *internally to the universe* and the formulas involved are *internal to the universe*. If that wasn't the case, $V=L$ would have to be a schema, if anything, and not a single axiom.

Comment: Also proposition 1.3 of http://library.msri.org/books/Book39/files/marker.pdf might be of interest to you.

Comment: @DanulG Thanks for that - it looks very much like my attempt, only cleaner. You should put that in an answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think that, in his book on the consistency of the continuum hypothesis (not the brief paper in the Proceedings of the National Academy but the book), Gödel uses what are now called the Gödel operations to define the constructible universe.  I think Shoenfield's book "Mathematical Logic" uses the same approach.  So the answer to the title of your question is yes.  The body of your question asks for something more difficult, not just getting $L$ but getting the individual stages of the constructible hierarchy.  That can undoubtedly be done by similar methods, but I don't recall ever seeing it worked out.  It would be tedious work, and I suspect nobody cared about it enough to do the work.

Comment: Your statement that getting $L$ is easier than $\operatorname{Def}(X)$ is surprising to me. I would expect that similar methods are employed to get either one. Furthermore, given $L$, you should be able to reconstruct $\operatorname{Def}(X)$ (at least for $X\in L$) as $\operatorname{Def}(X)={\cal P}(X)\cap L$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro No, Def$(X)$ is usually much smaller than $\mathcal P(X)\cap L$. For example, after you have $L_\omega$, the set of hereditarily finite sets, the only subsets that appear at the next step of the constructible hierarchy are the arithmetical sets.  But new subsets of $L_\omega$ continue to appear in $L_\alpha$ for arbitrarily large countable-in-$L$ ordinals $\alpha$.  On the other hand, I agree that "similar methods" should work; somebody just needs to check a lot of details, and that somebody won't be me (and might not exist at all).

Comment: I did the "tedious work" in an answer below, and it's not as bad as you are making it out to be. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

On a related note: Proposition 1.3 of http://library.msri.org/books/Book39/files/marker.pdf shows that the strategy for "defining definability" (as Kunen calls it in his Set Theory text (1st ed)) works for arbitrary structures. A proof of the proposition is in Marker's Model Theory text ([http://www.amazon.com/Model-Theory-Introduction-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/0387987606](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387987606)).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more or less direct translation of the satisfaction predicate to class-forming rules. It is sufficient to consider the base rules $x=y,\ x\in y$ and the wff operations $\lnot\phi,\ \phi\land\psi,\ \exists x\phi$. In order to handle parameters, we will actually define the set

$$\DeclareMathOperator{\defn}{\operatorname{Def}_{\Bbb N}(X)}\defn=\Big\{\{\vec y\in X^{\Bbb N}\mid (X,\in)\models\Phi(\vec y,\vec z)\}\Big|\,n\in\Bbb N,\Phi\mbox{ is a wff and } \vec z\in X^n\Big\},$$

where the sets are collections of sequences on $\Bbb N$, and the wff $\Phi$ has the first $n$ variables (or some finite subset) set to the $z_i$. From this we can pick out the one-parameter formulas as $$\operatorname{Def}(X)=\{x\in{\cal P}(X)\mid\{\vec y\in X^{\Bbb N}\mid y_1\in x\}\in\defn\}.$$

- For equality, we demand $\emptyset\in\defn$ and $n\in\Bbb N,y\in X\to\{x\in X^{\Bbb N}\mid x_n=y\}\in\defn$.
- Similarly for elementhood, we demand $i,j\in\Bbb N\to\{x\in X^{\Bbb N}\mid x_i\in x_j\}\in\defn$. Since we can write $x_i\in y\leftrightarrow \exists x_j(x_j=y\land x_i\in x_j)$ and $y\in x_i\leftrightarrow \exists x_j(x_j=y\land x_j\in x_i)$, it is not necessary to supply these sets, and similarly for $x_i=x_j\leftrightarrow \forall x_k(x_k\in x_i\leftrightarrow x_k\in x_j)$.
- Negation yields complementation, which is to say $A\in\defn\to X^{\Bbb N}\setminus A\in\defn$.
- Conjunction yields intersection, so $A,B\in\defn\to A\cap B\in\defn$.
- The existence quantifier is interpreted as \begin{align}
  \{x\in X^{\Bbb N}\mid (X,\in)\models \exists x_i,\phi\}&=\{x\in X^{\Bbb N}\mid \exists y\in X,(X,\in)\models \phi[x_i\to y]\}\end{align}
  and by induction we are assuming that the latter class abstraction is a member of $\defn$, so this yields the rule $n\in\Bbb N,A\in\defn\to\{x\in X^{\Bbb N}\mid \exists y\in X,x[x_i\to y]\in A\}\in\defn$ (where $x[x_i\to y]$ is the sequence on $\Bbb N$ defined by $x[x_i\to y]_i=y$ and $x[x_i\to y]_j=x_j$ for $j\ne i$.

The operation $\defn$ is thus defined as the smallest class which satisfies all these closures. Explicitly:

\begin{align}\defn&=\bigcap\Big\{D\mbox{ algebra on }X^{\Bbb N}\mid\\
&\land \forall i,j\in\Bbb N,\{x\in X^{\Bbb N}\mid x_i\in x_j\}\in D\\
&\land \forall n\in\Bbb N,\forall y\in X,\{x\in X^{\Bbb N}\mid x_n=y\}\in D\\
&\land \forall n\in\Bbb N,\forall A\in D,\{x\in X^{\Bbb N}\mid \exists y\in X,x[x_i\to y]\in A\}\in D\Big\}\end{align}

Since ${\cal P}(X^{\Bbb N})$ clearly satisfies all these conditions, the intersection is well-defined.